# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest ...| select -ExpandProperty inputfields (Not all "inputfields" revealed)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, powershell

If been using the below command-line to query simple web forms to identify all input fields that's needed to make a subsequent form POST.  However, I just ran into a relatively simple web form that has two input fields which aren't identified by the below command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://URI.com/index.aspx' -WebSession $Save | 
select -ExpandProperty inputfields | select name, value
```

.
.

In the below HTML source example, the above command will identify everything that has "input name" *(shown in html below)*; but, not other input types; such as, "select", "textarea".  I'd like to know "the" command-line that that can identify **ALL** input field types shown in the below HTML source example; and, any other unforeseen input types necessary to POST forms via Powershell Invoke-WebRequest.

HTML source:

```
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$LastName"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$email"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$phone"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><select name="MainPage$CountryDropDownList"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input name="MainPage$Description"..
..align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;"><textarea name="MainPage$DescribeHere"..
```

.
.

PS:  Should I use the names returned in the above Invoke-WebRequest command-line when POST'ing, or the names returned in the below command-line?  As, they are different.

```
$r.Forms[0] | $form.fields
```

EDIT:  The result of the above Invoke-WebRequest is (below).  As you can see ***MainPage_CountryDropDownList*** and ***MainPage_DescribeHere*** are missing below:

```
Key                                                                            Value
---                                                                            -----
__VIEWSTATE                                                                    /wEPDwULLTE5OT      
__EVENTVALIDATION                                                             /wEWEALtsrvJAgLkmtI29k...     
MainPage__FirstName                                                            Craig
MainPage__LastName                                                             Smith
MainPage__email                                                                 CraigSMith@gmail.com
MainPage__phone
MainPage__Project
MainPage__Submit                                                               Submit
```

**EDIT:**  I've never handled VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION before.  Can someone please confirm that I can simply POST the same VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION values I received when I first started my websession?  They're easy to store in a variable when the websession starts.  So, hopefully the values can stay as-is when I go to POST.

**EDIT:  For those suggesting Fiddler.  I already use that tool for getting the field names for a POST.**  I wanted specifically to get this information via command-line via something like the below solution (unfortunately, the regex is not correct, but for people who know regex well will know what I'm attempting to do:

```
$r.RawContent| sls -Pattern "(\<(input|select|textarea) name\=[""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1" -allmatches | %{$_.matches} | %{$_.value}
```

Comment: You should consider getting Fiddler, observe a POST session to the site and then inspect the body of the request.  That should give you enough info on how to construct the POST using IWR.

Answer (score 0):

`select` and `text` area are not Input fields [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input).

For what you are doing, I would recommend getting [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), start it up and monitor a POST that you do manually in the browser.  After submitting the form, go to Fiddler and find the session and take a look at the raw request.  If it is a post it will have a body that looks something like this:

```
usrname=keith&comment=some+pig.
```

Make that information the body that you pass to the Invoke-WebRequest -Body parameter e.g.:

```
$wr = Invoke-WebRequest http://URI.com/index.aspx -WebSession $Save -Method Post `
         -Body @{'MainPage$CountryDropDownList'="United States";'MainPage$DescribeHere'="some text"}
```

Just keep appending fields to this hashtable.  If the field name contains a `$` you have to put single quotes around the name otherwise, quotes are not required e.g. `-Body @{username="john";age="42"}`.

This is the `body` string we provide for post to a NetGear switch to enable/disable a port:

```
$portStateBody = "unit_no=1&java_port=&inputBox_interface1=&portDesc=&adminMode=${PortState}&physicalMode=Auto&auto_power_down=Disable&short_cable=Disable&linkTrap=Enable&frameSize=1518&CBox_1=checkbox&inputBox_interface2=&submt=16&cncel=&err_flag=0&err_msg=&selectedPorts=g${PortNumber}%3B&multiple_ports=1"
```

Note the PowerShell variables `${PortState}` and `${PortNumber}`.  This text was literally copy/pasted out of Fiddler's raw request tab and then I substituted the previously mentioned PowerShell where needed.

If you really want to regex the raw HTML for these elements, try this:

```
sls -inp $wr.RawContent -pattern '(?is)<(input|select|textarea)\s+.*?(?:id|name)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {"Element: $($_.Groups[1].value) key: $($_.Groups[2].value)"}
```

Comment: Yes, I already use Fiddler for getting form info.  I looking for a oommand-line solution for getting all form fields necessary to make a POST.  I'm certain it's possible to get what I want via the "RawContent" property and Regular Expressions.  Unfortunately, I dont know regex good enough to do this.  The closest I can come is with the below command-line; however, I'm doing something wrong when telling it to look look for the value in between the quotation marks:  $r.RawContent| sls -Pattern "(\<(input|select|textarea) name\=[""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1" -allmatches | %{$_.matches} | %{$_.value}

Comment: But Fiddler will show you all the form fields necessary to make a POST if you look at the raw request in Fiddler. I've done this for NetGear switches to enable/disable ports.  There are a bunch of form fields but it is just a matter of copying the raw body (with the form encoded fields) presenting that back to the POST URL with the appropriate values substituted.  I have updated my answer with an example from our NetGear switch module.

Comment: I updated my post to include the $r.RawContent | regex filter above.

Comment: Just to be clear, when I say `raw` I'm not talking about the response object.  I'm talking about the GUI tab in Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Just to be clear, I already use Fiddler regularly.  :)  Super simple to use.  I should have mentioned that originally.  I have a specific requirement to get these fields via powershell command-line.  I should be relatively close with the command-line I posted; but the regex filter isnt right.  I probably need to ask a separate regex question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Look at the regex I just added to this answer.